# Xpage doesn't load dijit.Dialog css

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

In Lotus Notes Designer 8.5.2, When creating a new xpage with a dijit dialog, the css doesn't show up.

How would I fix this? Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

  <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.Dialog"></xp:dojoModule>
  </xp:this.resources>

  <xp:div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="dialog1" style="display: none"
    title="Test">
    <xp:panel>Hello!</xp:panel>
  </xp:div>

  <xp:button value="Show Dialog" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
      <xp:this.script>
        <xp:executeClientScript>
          <xp:this.script>
            <![CDATA[dijit.byId("#{id:dialog1}").show();]]>
          </xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeClientScript>
      </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, that the dojo theme is disabled by default when one creates a blank xpage:

[image]

Once we set dojoTheme to true, then the page renders correctly:

[image]